# How is this method of fitting a Padé approximant to data called?

Tags: pade-approximation

[This website](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-rational-function-in-r-using-ordinary-least-squares-regression/) shows an implementation in R that fits a Padé approximant:

$$
R(x)= \frac{\sum_{j=0}^m a_j x^j}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x^k}=\frac{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_mx^m}{1+b_1 x+b_2x^2+\cdots+b_nx^n}
$$
to some data.

They write the function like this:
$$
y = \frac{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2}{1 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2}
$$

A bit of rearranging:

$$
y (1 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2
$$
$$
y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 - b_1 x y - b_2 x^2 y
$$

Now, they retrieve the coefficients using R's `lm()` function ([linear model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm)).

> Now we have a form that lm can work with. We just need to specify a
>   set of inputs that are powers of x (as in a traditional polynomial
>   fit), and a set of inputs that are y times powers of x. This may seem
>   like a strange thing to do, because we are making a model where we
>   would need to know the value of y in order to predict y. But the trick
>   here is that we will not try to use the fitted model to predict
>   anything; we will just take the coefficients out and rearrange them in
>   a function. The fit_pade function below takes a dataframe with x and y
>   values, fits an lm model, and returns a function of x that uses the
>   coefficents from the model to predict y:

```
fit_pade <- function(point_data){
  fit <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(y*x) + I(y*x^2), point_data)
  lm_coef <- as.list(coef(fit))
  names(lm_coef) <- c("a0", paste0(rep(c('a','b'), each=2), 1:2))

  with(lm_coef, function(x)(a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2)/(1 - b1*x - b2*x^2))
}
```

Some examples are available in [the link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-a-rational-function-in-r-using-ordinary-least-squares-regression/).

---

Is there a name for this method of fitting? Is there a paper, article, book, that describes this, either as is, or in more general terms? Preferably something citable?

Bonus question - can this be safely expanded to higher order polynomials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, this is not the way of building a Padé approximant but rather to fit a function over a given range by the ratio of two polynomials of given degrees. Remember that, as Taylor series, a Padé approximant is built around a given point.

Let us show it with $e^x$, the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of which (built around $x=0$) being
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2}{1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2}$$ and now use
$$y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 - b_1 x y - b_2 x^2 y$$ with $20$ equally spaced data points $x_i$ between $-1$ and $+1$ with $y_i=e^{x_i}$.

The linear regression would give the following results
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a_0 & +1.00003 & 0.00003 & \{+0.99997,+1.00010\} \\
 a_1 & +0.50444 & 0.00235 & \{+0.49943,+0.50946\} \\
 a_2 & +0.08385 & 0.00114 & \{+0.08142,+0.08628\} \\
 b_1 & -0.49522 & 0.00231 & \{-0.50015,-0.49029\} \\
 b_2 & +0.07957 & 0.00104 & \{+0.07736,+0.08178\} \\
\end{array}$$

Moreover, if you speak about least square fit, you must continue with nonlinear regression since what is "measured" is $y$ and not any of its possible transform. This linear regression gives you good estimates to start with; so, now, let us fit the true model
$$y = \frac{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2}{1 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2}$$
This would give
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a_0 & +1.00006 & 0.00003 & \{+1.00000,+1.00012\} \\
 a_1 & +0.50900 & 0.00234 & \{+0.50401,+0.51399\} \\
 a_2 & +0.08609 & 0.00118 & \{+0.08356,+0.08862\} \\
 b_1 & -0.49077 & 0.00228 & \{-0.49562,-0.48591\} \\
 b_2 & +0.07761 & 0.00099 & \{+0.07550,+0.07971\} \\
\end{array}$$

For sure, since this is a least square fit, over the range it will be better than the strict Padé approximant. Considering the norms
$$\Phi_1=\int_{-1}^{+1} \left(e^x-\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2}{1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{12}x^2} \right)^2\,dx=1.26 \times 10^{-6}$$

$$\Phi_2=\int_{-1}^{+1} \left(e^x-\frac{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2}{1 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2} \right)^2\,dx=6.81 \times 10^{-9}$$